Changing the role name of a nodejs container apps in application insights
I have using this piece of code in app.js file
var appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup('InstrumentationKey').start();
var client = appInsights.defaultClient;
appInsights.defaultClient.context.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "nodefront";


But even then, I can see only unknown_service:node in application map.
Can anyone help me in this


appInsights.defaultClient.context.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "nodefront";
But even then, I can see only unknown_service:node in application map.


Instead of hardcoding the key "ai.cloud.role", use appInsights.defaultClient.context.keys.cloudRole to dynamically access the key for the cloud role. This can be useful if you want to check consistency and avoid potential typos in the key name.

Code:
var appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup('InstrumentationKey').start();
var client = appInsights.defaultClient;

// Set the role name using the alternative approach
appInsights.defaultClient.context.tags[appInsights.defaultClient.context.keys.cloudRole] = "MyRoleName";

using appInsights.defaultClient.context.keys.cloudRole provides a more standardized and potentially safer way to access the key for the cloud role.

Reference:

Multiple roles for multi-component applications

Application Map in Azure Application Insights - Azure Monitor



Doesn't work either.
appinsights keys are "cloudRole":"ai.cloud.role","cloudRoleInstance":"ai.cloud.roleInstance","internalSdkVersion":"ai.internal.sdkVersion","internalAgentVersion":"ai.internal.agentVersion","internalNodeName":"ai.internal.nodeName"}; The tags are set to:
{"ai.cloud.role":"Platform Backend","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"------------"}. Neither the role nor the instance are shown in appinsights anymore. It was working fine sometimes in the past (like beginning of 2024). But recently its broken.
